# Nuxt 2 | TailwindCSS 3: Override component css

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I cant override my base button css in my hover button

**BaseButton.vue**

```html
<template>
  <button :class="$style.button" v-on="$listeners">
    <slot />
  </button>
</template>

<style module>
.button {
  @apply min-w-[200px] rounded-[2px] h-[53px] font-round font-medium bg-[#412F36] text-white outline-none;
}
</style>
```

**ButtonHover.vue**

```html
<template>
  <BaseButton class="border border-[#412F36] bg-transparent hover:bg-[#412F36] transition duration-300 text-black hover:text-white">
    <slot />
  </BaseButton>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: It's not really friendly to know what is not overwritten here. Still, nothing strange to me, you define a style on the inner button, it will keep it. Otherwise, some merge function (of tailwind properties) or a higher specificity would be a solution. But tailwind is not made to be used with CSS overrides.

Comment: @kissu Here an exemple of what I want to do, its working fine here, but not in my project https://codesandbox.io/s/kqw8io

Comment: *With scoped, the parent component's styles will not leak into child components. However, a child component's root node will be affected by both the parent's scoped CSS and the child's scoped CSS. This is by design so that the parent can style the child root element for layout purposes.* https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements